# Matplotlib Fill Missing Tic Labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot

I have a list of Pandas dataframes (example) data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[-9,-8,0,1,2,3], 'A':[3,6,4,1,7,19], 'B':[2,4,4,0,7,1]})
df1.set_index('Number',inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[0,5,6,7,8,9], 'A':[8,7,3,5,2,15], 'B':[1,7,1,1,1,3]})
df2.set_index('Number',inplace=True)

df_list = [df1, df2] #In reality there are more than two in the list
```

and I would am trying to plot them using Matplotlib:

```
nrow = 2
ncol = 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrow,ncol)

for i in range(nrow*ncol):
    #Convert 1D to 2D
    row = i / ncol
    col = i % ncol
    if i >= len(df_list):
        axs[row,col].axis('off')
    else:
        df_list[i]['A'].plot(kind='bar',
              ax=axs[row,col],
              ylim=(0,20),
              xlim=(-10,10),
              figsize=(20,15),
              color=('green'),
              legend=False,
              )
        df_list[i]['B'].plot(kind='bar',
              ax=axs[row,col],
              ylim=(0,20),
              xlim=(-10,10),
              figsize=(20,15),
              color=('yellow'),
              legend=False,
              )
```

The resulting plots look like this:
[image]
Everything looks fine except for the xtic labels which I expect to be spaced out according to its value (i.e., "-9" shouldn't be in the middle of the plot or "0" shouldn't be right next to "5", etc). In fact, since my x-range is roughly (-10,10), I want this full range to be displayed on the x-axis and for the colored bars to be positioned accordingly by their "number". One possible solution that I came up with was to fill in missing values from (-10,10) using Pandas but I assume there is a better/more obvious way to deal with this. I just haven't been able to identify that solution.

**Update:**

Thanks to Ajean's (and JD Long's) responses below, I am now using this Matplotlib code:

```
df_list = [df1, df2]

nrow = 2
ncol = 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrow,ncol,figsize=(20,15))

for i in range(nrow*ncol):
    #Convert 1D to 2D
    row = i / ncol
    col = i % ncol
    if i >= len(df_list):
        axs[row,col].axis('off')
    else:
        axs[row,col].bar(np.array(df_list[i].index)-0.5, df_list[i]['A'], width=1, color='green')
        axs[row,col].bar(np.array(df_list[i].index)-0.5, df_list[i]['B'], width=1, color='yellow')
        axs[row,col].set_xlim([-10,10])
        axs[row,col].set_ylim([0,20])
        axs[row,col].xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-10, 11, 1))
```

which produces this (wanted) result:

[image]

**Note:** The width of each bar is set to 1.0 and they have been shifted by -0.5 in order to center each bar above the tic marks.

Comment: As an extra aside, you are currently overlapping your bars, so the yellow ones will cover up the green ones if they are higher. Of course, you might be wanting to do this, but if you want a stacked bar chart you can use the `bottom` keyword FYI :).

Comment: @Ajean: Yes, I want my bars to overlap (yellow should be less than or equal to green) but I'm sure that I will have some use for a stacked bar chart in the future and so I will definitely keep "bottom" in mind. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Pandas has not (yet) given its bar chart wrapper functionality the capability to explicitly place the bar locations. The 0.14.0 "What's New" indicates that "coordinates of bar plots are now located on integer values (0.0, 1.0, 2.0 ...)", and nothing has changed up through 0.15.1, as far as I can tell.

Therefore, I'd skip the Pandas interface (which you are most definitely using) for this and use Matplotlib directly.

```
nrow = 1
ncol = 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrow,ncol)

for i in range(nrow*ncol):
    if i >= len(df_list):
        axs[i].axis('off')
    else:
        # You could theoretically turn this into a loop over your columns
        # with appropriate widths and offsets
        axs[i].bar(df_list[i].index-0.4, df_list[i]['A'], width=0.4, color='green')
        axs[i].bar(df_list[i].index, df_list[i]['B'], width=0.4, color='yellow')
```

The above code changes with your defined DataFrame list produces the plot below (for simplicity I eliminated the extra axes).

[image: bar chart at exact locations]

**NOTE**: The operation `df_list[i].index-0.4` under pandas 0.14.0 produces an error, which is a bug that has been fixed in 0.15.1.  You can get around it by converting the index to a normal numpy array first, or just upgrade pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a very good question. Thanks for having a reproducible example, that makes it so much easier to help.

The problem is that the Pandas bar chart code assumes categorical data on the x axis. Obviously you don't have categorical data. However there's no good way to tell Matplotlib that through the Pandas plot interface (that I know of).

The most obvious solution to me is the one you present of adding values. I would do that probably through a join. I'd join the existing dataframe to one with an index that had all the values I wanted on the x axis and do the join with the `how='outer'` option.

Comment: Thanks! Did you mean "Matplotlib bar chart" rather than Pandas? Maybe I'm mistaken but I'm under the impression that I am plotting directly with Matplotlib (i.e., I'm not doing anything like "df1.plot(kind="bar")". If this is correct then is there a way to directly tell Matplotlib how to handle the x-labels? Or is there a different way to achieve the same visual result using Matplotlib but with, say, a different plot, a different visualization (draw rectangular shapes instead), or use different parameters, etc.

Comment: you're absolutely doing `df1.plot(kind="bar")` when you call `df_list[i]['B'].plot(kind='bar'` because `df_list[i]['B']` is a dataframe. Now that said, Pandas calls matplotlib, but you are most certainly using the Pandas interface.